# I'm trying to migrate from Cakephp 2.5 to Cakephp 3.3 but facing some issues

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

> Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Error\error500.ctp" is missing. #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(588): Cake\View\View->_getViewFileName('Error\error500') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(366): Cake\View\View->render('error500', 'error') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(333): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessageSafe('error500') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(336): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage('error500') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(194): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage('error') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ErrorHandler.php(144): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->render() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php(180): Cake\Error\ErrorHandler->_displayException(Object(Cake\Error\PHP7ErrorException)) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php(164): Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Cake\Error\PHP7ErrorException)) #8 [internal function]: Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->wrapAndHandleException(Object(Cake\Error\PHP7ErrorException)) #9 {main} 
>   File C:\xampp\htdocs\mmdb11\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ErrorHandler.php 
>   Line: 156

Comment: there is an error of missing file in Error folder

Comment: Could you post more information (host system, etc ...). Also please format the question, you just posted a stack trace which is almost unreadable in this format.

Comment: or you can you just give me hint to convert the code of 2.5 to 3.3 beacuse not pro. Both the version follow different procedure so how to convert it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those versions are not compatible. You could update to CakePHP 2.9.1 (or any other version in 2.x branch). CakePHP 3 uses namspaces, and **a lot** of code has changed.

basicly You would have to rewrite Your application to use CakePHP 3.3